# onDestroy and onCreate is called when sleep button is pressed

Tags: android, android-manifest

my app is running in Landscape Mode.when my phone is put to sleep then onDestroy() and then onCreate() is called automatically.i already declared android:configChanges="orientation" and android:screenOrientation="landscape".please tell me what to do ,to avoid this problem.
I've also attached the xml file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="m.example.ghb1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="m.example.ghb1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity android:name=".PlayActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"

            >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: and where is the problem?

Comment: By sleep button, do you mean 'Display OFF' button?

Answer (score 0):

> when my phone is put to sleep then onDestroy() and then onCreate() is called automatically.

android is allowed to call onDestroy (destroy your app and activities) whenever it like, you need to prepare your app for such situation - here is good article on that:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

> i already declared android:configChanges="orientation" and android:screenOrientation="landscape".

this is a common hack to prevent android from recreating activities, programmers that use it often forgets that system might destroy activites in many other situations

Answer (score 0):

Android can call `onDestroy()` whenever it needs to free memory for some other task. What you can do is to override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isRequired", true);
  savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("myInt", 1);
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
  // etc.
}
```

The Bundle is essentially a way of storing a NVP ("Name-Value Pair") map, and it will get passed in to onCreate and also onRestoreInstanceState where you'd extract the values like this:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
  double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```